# How to avoid multiple scroll events in virtualisation in angular grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, virtualization

I have a grid control written in angular, it has implement Virtualization.

The Virtualization is implemented as following.

1. load the first 60 records in the grid on initial load.
2. every time user scrolls down load another 60 records.
3. the records to be loaded are decided by the **scrollTop** position if the scroll.

My solution has the following issues:

- when we load the records in scroll down, as new rows are loaded in the grid, scroll events is fired for each loaded row.
- by this, it triggers 60 scroll events, on each scroll, and this causes the chaining of the scroll events.
- so in the end, the page is scrolled till the end of the screen.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can You Please share a working example, On Stackblitz, or some reference code snippets

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.